# Get the current coordinates of an item on a Canvas widget given its item handle?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, coordinates, items

From reading the docs (http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#reference), there doesn't appear to me to be a way to do this. Just wanted to make sure I hadn't made a mistake. (I.e. one would have to internally store the coordinates of various items in a program if one wanted to do boundary checking, for example. [e.g. Check, before moving an oval, that it will not bump into a wall, represented by a line on the current canvas, the coordinate information of which is also stored.])

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [coords](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.coords-method) method:

```
coords = the_canvas.coords(item_id)
```